# Enumeration in CV without a "bulletpoint" list

Tags: text, latex

I am listing a couple of skills in my CV which I do not want to present as a enumeration with line breaks. I want to avoid line breaks because this introduces a lot of space vertically.

The CV is for jobs in data science/biotech.

I have something in mind like:

**My Skills:

Cooking in my free time | Skying in wintertime with my friends whenever I have time | Reading a lot of books about deep ocean exploration in the early years | Sleeping**

The obvious thing is to use a delimiter such as pipes (or dots) as shown above. As in the dummy example some of the items are quite long.

But I am not convinced with this approach. Any idea for a nice alternative?

If you think my approach is the only feasable, which delimiter would you choose?

Plus: I am doing my CV in LaTeX. If there is a neat trick in LaTeX I do not mind.

Answer (score 5):

Inline bullets would work as long as they stand out clearly enough. I think the pipes are a little weak for this purpose, so maybe use something bolder:

> ### My Skills
>
> ■ Cooking in my free time ■ Skiing in wintertime with my friends whenever I have time ■ Reading a lot of books about deep ocean exploration in the early years ■ Sleeping

Alternatively, if each item starts with a verb, perhaps you could use these to draw attention to each item. Something like this perhaps:

> ### My Skills
>
> »**Cooking** in my free time »**Skiing** in wintertime with my friends whenever I have time »**Reading** a lot of books about deep ocean exploration in the early years »**Sleeping**

Comment: The second suggestion is a good one which I did not think about. I will try.

Comment: If you're tight on space you could just list the four verbs and leave out the details.